# Bootstrap form add field dynamically

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, field

I have created a bootstrap form and I want to add fields on the fly before the submit button is pressed. For example, when a user clicks 1 child, another div should ask Child's name and age and if the user selected 2 kids, it should ask for both kids before the user reaches the submit button. Just like hotels.com and expedia.com ask for child age when booking:
My code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Check</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="workarea">
          <center>Let us know your situation <br><br>
          <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="age">I am </label>
          <input type="number" name="age" min=0 max=99 class="form-control" placeholder="Age" /> years old <br>
          <select class="selectpicker form-control" required name="maritalStatus">
            <option value="married">Married</option>
            <option value="single">Single</option>
          </select>
          <label for="kids">with <label>
          <input type="number" name="kids" min=0 max=5 class="form-control" placeholder="kids"/>

        </center><br>
          <center><input type="submit" value="Get me started" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" name="firstpage"/></center>
          </form>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript/JQuery will do it. Something like `$( ".form-inline" ).append( "<input type='text' value='example'>" );` may work...

Comment: the problem with append is that there needs to be button clicked for append() or after()

Comment: No there doesn't... you can use any selector you wish (on document load, on field filled out, focus, etc)...